# Creating tags for taxonomy ranks?

Tags: discussion, tags

Since this forum is welcoming ecologist ([Do we accept the ecology community?](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/530/do-we-accept-the-ecology-community)) I suppose that a number of questions regarding the species or taxonomy rank will increase.

It is creating specialsed taxonomy tags (eg. for orders - [orthoptera](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthoptera), [diptera](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diptera), [coleoptera](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coleoptera), ...) desirable for the future of biology.se?

When the community grows it will be much easier for questioners get answer by targeting posts directly to experts or people interest in given groups. On the other hand it can result in complications with hierarchy tags ([Tagging hierarchy - best practices for adding more “general” tags](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3551/tagging-hierarchy-best-practices-for-adding-more-general-tags)
).

Comment: I think in most cases, order-level tags are going to be too numerous and not really all that helpful. I don't think we get enough questions that are so specific to one given order - even for the species-identification questions, it is quite likely that the person asking the question or people looking for answers to similar questions may have no clue about the order. Some orders would be an exception, like primates, because it is an order familiar to most even with no experience in taxonomy, as well as a common area of interest.